# Dataflow in Azure Synapse refuses to be cloned directly: “Error while saving entities. Details: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded”

Tags: azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-pipeline

The Dataflow in question consists of the following elements:

- 2x Source
- 1x Sink
- 4x Derived Column
- 2x Union
- 1x Select
- 2x Filter
- 2x Aggregate
- 4x Flowlet: referencing the same Flowlet, consisting of:
  -- 1x Aggregate
  -- 1x Select

When used inside a pipeline it works as expected. In Dataflow debug mode I already receive the following error:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded” & “executeJobPreviewDataQuery no active stream for job=<job_id>, jobState=Completed

When trying to clone the Dataflow in the Synapse UI an empty Dataflow gets created and the following error is displayed upon publishing:

> Error while saving entities. Details: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

However, simply coping the JSON into a new Dataflow works.

I'm not able to test this in ADF and hence can't tell if it is a Synapse specific issue.

**update:** seems to be a **Synapse/ADF UI issue**, since cloning is possible, if the Dataflow has not been opened before (e.g. after a refresh in the UI). Furthermore, those results are independent of the Dataflow name.

raw Dataflow script:

```
parameters{
    hours_history as integer (1),
    column_names as string[] (["a","b","c","d"])
}
source(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: true,
    modifiedAfter: (currentUTC()-hours($hours_history)),
    format: 'parquet',
    fileSystem: 'fs1',
    folderPath: 'fp1',
    compressionCodec: 'none',
    mode: 'read') ~> BNBack
source(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: true,
    enableCdc: true,
    mode: 'read',
    skipInitialLoad: false,
    format: 'parquet',
    fileSystem: 'fs1',
    folderPath: 'fp1') ~> BLCDC
deduplicatePreCDC@deduplicatedOutput compose(composition: 'Flowlet_DropEventHubMetadata') ~> dropEventHubMetadata1@(output1)
dropTempGroupCol compose(composition: 'Flowlet_DropEventHubMetadata') ~> dropEventHubMetadata2@(output1)
dropEventHubMetadata2@output1 compose(composition: 'Flowlet_FullDeduplication') ~> deduplicateRight@(deduplicatedOutput)
dropEventHubMetadata1@output1 compose(composition: 'Flowlet_FullDeduplication') ~> deduplicateLeft@(deduplicatedOutput)
BNBack compose(composition: 'Flowlet_FullDeduplication') ~> deduplicatePreNBack@(deduplicatedOutput)
BLCDC compose(composition: 'Flowlet_FullDeduplication') ~> deduplicatePreCDC@(deduplicatedOutput)
deduplicateRight@deduplicatedOutput derive(custom_count = 2) ~> addCountRight
addCountRight, addCountLeft union(byName: true)~> union1
deduplicateLeft@deduplicatedOutput derive(custom_count = 1) ~> addCountLeft
union1 aggregate(groupBy(temp_groupCol = sha2(256,byNames($column_names))),
    custom_count = sum(custom_count),
        each(match(not(name=="custom_count")), $$ = first($$))) ~> aggregate1
aggregate1 filter(toInteger(byName('custom_count'))==1) ~> filterLeftNew
deduplicatePreCDC@deduplicatedOutput derive(custom_count_pre = 2) ~> addCountPreCDC
addCountPreCDC, addCountPreNBack union(byName: true)~> unionPre
deduplicatePreNBack@deduplicatedOutput derive(custom_count_pre = 1) ~> addCountPreNBack
unionPre aggregate(groupBy(temp_groupCol_pre = sha2(256,byNames($column_names))),
    custom_count_pre = sum(custom_count_pre),
        each(match(not(name=="custom_count_pre")), $$ = first($$))) ~> aggregatePre
aggregatePre filter(toInteger(byName('custom_count_pre'))==1) ~> filterWithoutNewCDC
filterWithoutNewCDC select(mapColumn(
        each(match(not(in(['custom_count_pre','temp_groupCol_pre'],name))))
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> dropTempGroupCol
filterLeftNew sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    format: 'parquet',
    fileSystem: 'fs1',
    folderPath: 'fp2',
    compressionCodec: 'none',
    umask: 0022,
    preCommands: [],
    postCommands: [],
    saveOrder: 1,
    mapColumn(
        each(match(not(in(['custom_count','temp_groupCol'],name))))
    )) ~> L2
```

Comment: Can you provide your dataflow JSON for better understanding of the issue?

Comment: Have added the script part above (see also my updated finding). I'm quite convinced that some UI imposed limit is at play here.